# Не происходит коннекта между каруселями JCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jcarousel

Пытаюсь законнектить 2 карусели JCarousel, которые вызываю ajax'om при нажатии на блок [портфолио](http://test1.so-use.ru/nashi-raboty.html).
Обе карусели - работают, но коннекта не происходит, хотелось бы узнать почему?

Код вызова карусели:

```js
(function($) {
    var connector = function(itemNavigation, carouselStage) {
        return carouselStage.jcarousel('items').eq(itemNavigation.index());
    };

    $(function() {
        var carouselStage      = $('.carousel-stage').jcarousel();
        var carouselNavigation = $('.carousel-navigation').jcarousel();

        carouselNavigation.jcarousel('items').each(function() {
            var item = $(this);
   
            var target = connector(item, carouselStage);

            item
                .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                    carouselNavigation.jcarousel('scrollIntoView', this);
                    item.addClass('active');
                })
                .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                    item.removeClass('active');
                })
                .jcarouselControl({
                    target: target,
                    carousel: carouselStage
                });
        });

        // Setup controls for the stage carousel
        $('.prev-stage')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '-=1'
            });

        $('.next-stage')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '+=1'
            });

        // Setup controls for the navigation carousel
        $('.prev-navigation')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '-=1'
            });

        $('.next-navigation')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '+=1'
            });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Шаблон:

```html
<div id="hide_carousel_holder" class="hide_carousel_holder">
 <span id="close_span" class="close_span">X</span>
 <div class="connected-carousels">
  <div class="stage">
   <div class="carousel carousel-stage" id="carousel-stage">
    <ul id="result">

    </ul>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="prev prev-stage" data-jcarouselcontrol="true"><span>‹</span></a>
   <a href="#" class="next next-stage" data-jcarouselcontrol="true"><span>›</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
   <div class="carousel carousel-navigation" id="carousel-navigation">
    <ul id="result1">

    </ul>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="prev prev-navigation">‹</a>
   <a href="#" class="next next-navigation">›</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Может кто сталкивался с подобным? Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

Comment: что значит законнектить?

Comment: Что бы одна из галерей служила навигатором для второй, брал вот от сюда http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/connected-carousels/

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, может кому пригодится. Проблему решил переносом объявления коннекта в момент передачи значений из ajax в html а именно:

```js
$(".ajax_link").click(function(event){
  console.log('click')
  target = this;
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/index-ajax.php",
    data:{
      q:"assets/snippets/getContent/getContent.php",
      id: $(this).attr('data-id')
    },
    
    success:function(response) {
      $("#result").html(response);
      $("#result1").html(response);
      $('#carousel-stage').jcarousel('reload');
      $('#carousel-navigation').jcarousel('reload');
      var connector = function(itemNavigation, carouselStage) {
        return carouselStage.jcarousel('items').eq(itemNavigation.index());
      };
      $(function() {
        var carouselStage= $('.carousel-stage').jcarousel();
        var carouselNavigation = $('.carousel-navigation').jcarousel();
        
        carouselNavigation.jcarousel('items').each(function() {
          var item = $(this);
          
          var target = connector(item, carouselStage);
          
          item
          .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
            
            carouselNavigation.jcarousel('scrollIntoView', this);
            item.addClass('active');
          })
          .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
            item.removeClass('active');
          })
          .jcarouselControl({
            target: target,
            carousel: carouselStage
          });
        });
      });
      
    }
  });
});
```

После этого все заработало